# Difference between static with and without public

Tags: java

I have a Class *RequestHelper* where I store methods for http-Requests to initiate Requests from different Activities.

E.g. there is this one:

```
class RequestHelper {
    static void loginUser(String email, String password, final Context activityContext) {
    // do request stuff
    }
}
```

Is there any difference if I put a public in front of it like in the following example or is it just nonsense to do so?

```
class RequestHelper {
    public static void loginUser(String email, String password, final Context activityContext) {
    // do request stuff
    }
}
```

Both versions do work as planned, so is there any difference at all?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in

Comment: The first one with no public should be having a package-private scope while the second is available to all classes

Comment: *"Is there any difference if I put a public in front of it"* Yes: It will be available outside the package your class is in. See the linked question's answers for details. :-)